# How does one copy 1D array to another 1D array and 2D array?

Tags: arrays, vba, excel

Suppose I have an array (1,2,3,4), then I want to copy it to another 1D array and 2D array. I use this sub-routine:

```
Sub CopyArray()
    Dim Arr1(), Arr2()
    ReDim Arr3(1 To m, 1 To n)

    Arr1 = Array(1, 2, 3, 4)

    For i = 1 To 4
        Arr2(i) = Arr1(i)
        Arr3(1, i) = Arr1(i)
    Next i

End Sub
```

It kept getting an error "subscript out of range". I also tried

```
Sub CopyArray()
    Dim Arr1(), Arr2()

    Arr1 = Array(1, 2, 3, 4)

    For i = 1 To 4
        Arr2(i) = Arr1(i)
    Next i

End Sub
```

or

```
Sub CopyArray()
    Dim Arr1()
    ReDim Arr3(1 To m, 1 To n)

    Arr1 = Array(1, 2, 3, 4)

    For i = 1 To 4
        Arr3(1, i) = Arr1(i)
    Next i

End Sub
```

but none of them worked. How does one copy 1D array to another 1D array and 2D array properly?

Comment: What is `m` and what is `n` in first piece of code? ;)

Comment: Also if you search google there are lot of answers for this :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Simplest way to copy one array to another in your case would be to declare the arrays as `Variant`. This way you will not have to **loop**

**Example of 1D array**

```
Sub CopyArray()
    Dim x As Variant
    Dim y As Variant

    x = Array(1, 2, 3)

    y = x '<~~ Directly clone the array

    For i = LBound(y) To UBound(y)
        Debug.Print y(i)
    Next i
End Sub
```

**Example of 2D Array**

```
Sub CopyArray()
    Dim x As Variant
    Dim y As Variant

    x = Array(1, 2, 3)

    y = Application.Transpose(x) '<~~ Transpose it

    For i = LBound(y) To UBound(y)
        Debug.Print y(i, 1)
    Next i
End Sub
```

Answer (score 1):

First your `i` has to start at `0` because it is where arrays start. For example `Arr1(1) = 2` and not `1` in your code. Secondly you have to `Redim` your second array so it has the same size as your first one. Here is a piece of code to help you out:

```
Dim Arr1(), Arr2()

Arr1 = Array(1, 2, 3, 4)
ReDim Arr2(0 To 3)

For i = 0 To 3
    Arr2(i) = Arr1(i)
Next i
```

Comment: Arrays don't have to start at 0. They run from whatever to whatever depending on the boundaries that you set.

Comment: @Tom I lacked of clarity on this one. I was referring to the index which starts at 0 when you don't set it to a different value.

Answer (score 1):

Here you have two things to keep in mind.

**Firstly**, you have to give a dimension to `Arr2` via `ReDim`, for example you can do

```
ReDim Arr2(ubound(Arr1))
```

Before the `For` loop, since it has no dimension beforehand: `Dim Arr2()` declares an array that you have to change in dimension afterwards.

**Secondly**, since arrays start at `0` in VBA, you are having an issue populating the data from `Arr1` that ranges from 0 to 3 and `Arr3` that ranges from 1 to 4 (from the declaration `ReDim Arr3(1 To m, 1 To n)`).
A good practice would have to use either all arrays starting at 0 or 1 but not both.

You can enforce the array dimension by using the `Option Base 1` command ([here look at the documention from MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa266179(v=vs.60).aspx) ) and then all your arrays will start at 1.

As a consequence you can have it in two ways:

**1- Using Base 1**

```
Option Base 1

Sub CopyArray()

    Dim Arr1(), Arr2(), Arr3()

    Arr1 = Array(1, 2, 3, 4)

    'Since I assume you already have values for m and n, I give values for the code to work in our example
    m = 1
    n = 4

    ReDim Arr3(m, n)
    ReDim Arr2(ubound(Arr1))

    For i = LBound(Arr1) To UBound(Arr1)
        Arr2(i) = Arr1(i)
        Arr3(1, i) = Arr1(i)
    Next i

End Sub
```

**2- Keeping the 0 lower bound**

```
Sub CopyArray()

    Dim Arr1(), Arr2(), Arr3()

    Arr1 = Array(1, 2, 3, 4)

    'Same as above
    m = 1
    n = 4

    ReDim Arr3(m, n)
    ReDim Arr2(ubound(Arr1))

    For i = LBound(Arr1) To UBound(Arr1)
        Arr2(i) = Arr1(i)
        Arr3(1, i) = Arr1(i)
    Next i

End Sub
```

Notice that there is little difference between both codes, but one has all its arrays starting at 1 and not 0.

I'd recommend you to read also [Lbound](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa445057(v=vs.60).aspx) and [Ubound](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa263396(v=vs.60).aspx) for the lower and upper bound of arrays.

Comment: Both of your code doesn't work. The same error as the OP's occurred.

Comment: Thanks, I added value to `m` and `n` for this example to work.

Answer (score 1):

The following code works fine:

```
Sub CopyArray()
    Dim Arr1(), Arr2(3)

    Arr1 = Array(1, 2, 3, 4)

    For i = 0 To 3
        Arr2(i) = Arr1(i)
    Next i

End Sub
```

Note that the declaration does **not** specify the number of elements in the array. Instead, it specifies the upper bound of the array. If your module does not contain an Option Base statement, the lower bound is assumed to be zero. So, the declaration above, `Dim Arr2(3)`, is the same as

```
Dim Arr2(0 To 3) As Variant
```

You may check that `Arr1(1)` is equal to 2, not 1 as you might think. Try to add the following line below the `Next i` to check each element of `Arr1`:

```
Debug.Print Arr1(0), Arr1(1), Arr1(2), Arr1(3)
```

For the best programming practice, you should **always** explicitly specify both the lower and upper bound for the array, either in the `Dim` or a `ReDim` statement. So your first code should be

```
Sub CopyArray()
Dim Arr1(), Arr2(), Arr3()

Arr1 = Array(1, 2, 3, 4)

ReDim Arr2(UBound(Arr1))
ReDim Arr3(1 To 1, 0 To 3)

For i = LBound(Arr1) To UBound(Arr1)
    Arr2(i) = Arr1(i)
    Arr3(1, i) = Arr1(i)
Next i
    Debug.Print Join(Arr2, ",")
    Debug.Print Arr3(1, 0), Arr3(1, 1), Arr3(1, 2), Arr3(1, 3)
End Sub
```

**Note:** The function `Debug.Print` writes values to the **Immediate  Window** to see the output of your code. To view this window select **View** ►**Immediate Window** from the menu or use keyboard shortcut <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>G</kbd>.